# Does anyone know how to get rid of the jsdebug requests from my .net web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We have a ajax listprovider for typeahead text fields in our webform site.  Every page now requests a listprovider.asmx/jsdebug with no caching parameters etc.

How do we turn that off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make sure that the debug attribute is set to false in your web.config, it is part of the compilation element in system.web.

Hope that helps...

Steve